# The type or namespace name 'Neodynamic' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

i want to use the neodynamic image draw sdk and keep getting this error on build i have searched for solutions but none work i have this is my current code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using DevPro.Data.Enums;
    using YGOPro_Launcher.CardDatabase;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Data.SQLite;
    using DevPro_CardManager.Properties;
    using Neodynamic.SDK;

namespace Outlaws_CardManager
{
    public partial class cardmaker : Form
    {
        public cardmaker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TopLevel = false;
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Visible = true;
        }

        private void GenerateCard()
        {
            //Get the info to create the card
            string cardname = "";
            string cardid = "";
            string level = "";
            string race = "";
            string attribute = "";
            string atk = "";
            string def = "";
            string type1 = "";
            string type2 = "";
            string stype = "";
            string traptype = "";
            string mainpicture = "";
            string layout = "Left";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CardName.Text))
            {
                cardname = CardName.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CardID.Text))
            {
                cardid = CardID.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ATK.Text))
            {
                atk = ATK.Text;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DEF.Text))
            {
                def = DEF.Text;
            }

            ImageDraw imgDraw = new ImageDraw();
            //Basic settings for Card
            imgDraw.Canvas.AutoSize = false;
            imgDraw.ImageFormat = ImageDrawFormat.Png;
            //Set card size
            imgDraw.Canvas.Width = 400;
            imgDraw.Canvas.Height = 250;

            //Create main decorative shape element
            RectangleShapeElement rect1 = new RectangleShapeElement();
            rect1.X = 10;
            rect1.Y = 10;
            rect1.Width = 380;
            rect1.Height = 230;

            rect1.Roundness = 20;
            rect1.StrokeWidth = 0;
            //Set background
            rect1.Fill.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
            //Add element to output image
            imgDraw.Elements.Add(rect1);



            //Create top decorative shape element
            RectangleShapeElement rect2 = new RectangleShapeElement();
            rect2.X = 20;
            rect2.Y = 20;
            rect2.Width = 360;
            rect2.Height = 170;
            rect2.Roundness = 10;
            rect2.StrokeWidth = 0;
            rect2.Fill.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            //Add element to output image
            imgDraw.Elements.Add(rect2);

            //Create bottom decorative shape element
            RectangleShapeElement rect3 = new RectangleShapeElement();
            rect3.X = 30;
            rect3.Y = 130;
            rect3.Width = 340;
            rect3.Height = 100;
            rect3.Roundness = 10;
            rect3.StrokeWidth = 1;
            rect3.StrokeFill.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
            rect3.Fill.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            //Add element to output image
            imgDraw.Elements.Add(rect3);





            //Create an ImageElement to wrap the user logo
            if (mainpicture.Length > 0 && System.IO.File.Exists(mainpicture))
            {
                ImageElement imgElemLogo = new ImageElement();
                //Get user logo from disk
                imgElemLogo.Source = ImageSource.File;
                imgElemLogo.SourceFile = mainpicture;
                //Logo Layout
                if (layout == "Right")
                {
                    imgElemLogo.X = 40;
                    imgElemLogo.Y = 40;
                }
                else
                {
                    imgElemLogo.X = 400 - (50 + 40); //Canvas Width - (Logo Width + X Margin)
                    imgElemLogo.Y = 40;
                }
                //Apply Resize logo
                Resize resizeLogo = new Resize();
                resizeLogo.Width = 50;
                resizeLogo.LockAspectRatio = LockAspectRatio.WidthBased;
                imgElemLogo.Actions.Clear();
                imgElemLogo.Actions.Add(resizeLogo);
                //Add element to output image
                imgDraw.Elements.Add(imgElemLogo);
            }


            //Create TextElement objects for each fields

            if (cardname.Length > 0)
            {
                TextElement txtElemName = new TextElement();
                txtElemName.AutoSize = false;
                txtElemName.Font.Name = "Arial";
                txtElemName.Font.Size = 14f;
                txtElemName.Font.Unit = FontUnit.Point;
                txtElemName.Font.Bold = true;
                txtElemName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                txtElemName.Text = cardname;
                txtElemName.TextQuality = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
                txtElemName.X = 40;
                txtElemName.Y = 40;
                txtElemName.Width = 320;
                txtElemName.Height = 20;
                if (layout == "Left")
                {
                    txtElemName.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtElemName.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
                }
                //Add element to output image
                imgDraw.Elements.Add(txtElemName);
            }

            if (cardid.Length > 0)
            {
                TextElement txtElemJob = new TextElement();
                txtElemJob.AutoSize = false;
                txtElemJob.Font.Name = "Arial";
                txtElemJob.Font.Size = 10f;
                txtElemJob.Font.Unit = FontUnit.Point;
                txtElemJob.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                txtElemJob.Text = cardid;
                txtElemJob.TextQuality = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
                txtElemJob.X = 40;
                txtElemJob.Y = 64;
                txtElemJob.Width = 320;
                txtElemJob.Height = 14;
                if (layout == "Left")
                {
                    txtElemJob.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtElemJob.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
                }
                //Add element to output image
                imgDraw.Elements.Add(txtElemJob);
            }

            if (atk.Length > 0)
            {
                TextElement txtElemAddress = new TextElement();
                txtElemAddress.AutoSize = false;
                txtElemAddress.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
                txtElemAddress.Font.Italic = true;
                txtElemAddress.Font.Size = 11f;
                txtElemAddress.Font.Unit = FontUnit.Point;
                txtElemAddress.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                txtElemAddress.Text = atk + "\n" + race;
                txtElemAddress.TextQuality = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
                txtElemAddress.X = 40;
                txtElemAddress.Y = 130;
                txtElemAddress.Width = 160;
                txtElemAddress.Height = 50;
                if (layout == "Left")
                {
                    txtElemAddress.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtElemAddress.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
                }
                //Add element to output image
                imgDraw.Elements.Add(txtElemAddress);
            }

            if (attribute.Length > 0 || atk.Length > 0)
            {
                TextElement txtElemPhone = new TextElement();
                txtElemPhone.AutoSize = false;
                txtElemPhone.Font.Name = "Georgia";
                txtElemPhone.Font.Size = 10f;
                txtElemPhone.Font.Unit = FontUnit.Point;
                txtElemPhone.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                txtElemPhone.Text = "Phone: " + attribute + "\n" + atk;
                txtElemPhone.TextQuality = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
                txtElemPhone.X = 200;
                txtElemPhone.Y = 180;
                txtElemPhone.Width = 160;
                txtElemPhone.Height = 50;
                if (layout == "Right")
                {
                    txtElemPhone.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtElemPhone.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
                }
                //Add element to output image
                imgDraw.Elements.Add(txtElemPhone);
            }

            //generate image card and preview it
            CardImg.Image = imgDraw.GetOutputImage();
        }

    }
}
```

has anyone had a problem like this before please explain how fixed.

Comment: Did you reference the DLL in your project?

Comment: yes i have referenced the dll

Comment: heres a pic to my references http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/9840/ufm8.png

Comment: Did you really need to post _all_ of that code in order to show us the problem?

Comment: no but last time i didnt post all my code and people had a go and downvoted me

Comment: The secret is posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). We can't help you if there's no code (or the code doesn't have the problem you describe). But no one wants to wade through pages and pages of code either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such problems might occur if your Project's Target-Framework and your referenced assembly framework version are incompatible.

So as I may presume, you should take the following steps:

Right-Click on your Project -> Properties -> Target Framework -> Make Sure it is ***not*** set on *Client Profile* and if it does than choose **.NET Framework 4** or **4.5** (according to the referenced-assembly targeted FW).

**Update:** Here is a snapshot of the settings

[image: Target framework settings]